# Rythm template engine and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, rythm

Has anybody managed to get Rythm template engine to work with Google Appengine?

Thanks

Comment: Hi what's the issue you encountered getting rythm work with GAE?

Comment: No issues, since we haven't tried it yet. That is what I was trying to find out before jumping on a ship.

Comment: Probably you want to be the pioneer and let us know what happened ;-) Note you don't need to abandon your groovy template when migrating to Rythm. All you want to do is to migrate your groovy template files one by one into app/rythm folder, they will be processed by Rythm engine. Those who don't have rythm template file created will still get processed by groovy engine. - And yes, I am talking in PlayFramework context.

Comment: Hi you must be, Green Luo. Indeed Rythm looks really tempting. But as we are using Velocity it is not that easy to switch. Especially since many other libraries have Velocity wrappers integrated. We don't use  Play, nor  Groovy. But I don't think that makes a difference. Rythm from my initial checks seems to have all the velocity features, unless I missed something.

Comment: Hi husayt, glad to know that Rythm catch the eyes from outside of play community :) Note the rythmengine website doc is a little bit outdated, please go http://rythmengine.com/document/play/home for latest doc. The doc is for play-rythm, but most of it apply to pure rythm and you just ignore the play specific content which is explicitly marked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rythm now (version [1.0.0-20120505](http://rythmengine.com/public/rythm-1.0.0-20120505-dist.zip)) works on GAE. There is a demo app running at http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com/

And the source code of the demo app: https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-rythm-demo