# Rythm template engine with GAE/J: AccessControlException in even simplest case

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, rythm

I am trying to use the [Rythm template engine](http://rythmengine.org/) on Google App Engine/Java devserver (GAE/J).  This is a bare-bones install with nothing but Rythm added to the base GAE devserver.

The question [Rythm template engine and GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201712/rythm-template-engine-and-gae) doesn't quite answer my question (the source code pointed to in the answer gives a 404 error).

Started by adding the following code to my servlet code:

```
response.getWriter().println(Rythm.render("Successfully logged in as: @who",
                user.getNickname()));
```

and I get:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/var/folders/91/nv5sbz412b188nk22m644mq80000gn/T/__rythm" "read")
```

I thought this is happening because the Rythm template engine tries to look in `/var` to see whether to treat first parameter to `Rythm.render` as a filename or not, and GAE throws the `AccessControlException` because you're not supposed to access the filesystem outside of the war.

I then added the following lines before the call to `Rythm.render` (these are essentially copy-and-pasted from Rythm's [HelloWorld example](http://rythmengine.org/doc/tutorial.md#hello)):

```
// use Map to store the configuration
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// tell rythm where to find the template files
map.put("home.template", ".");
// init Rythm with our predefined configuration
Rythm.init(map);
```

Still get that same exception. Changing the "." to "/" as value for `home.template` gives:

```
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/Successfully logged in as: @who" "read")
```

When I tried:

```
map.put("home.template", this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
```

I still get the same exception. Why is Rythm looking at `/var/folders/91/nv5sbz412b188nk22m644mq80000gn/T/__rythm` at all? Stack trace is available at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dOUTDGuy2AWjR3Tmt2WTlkOUE/edit?usp=sharing (is there a better way to share a stack trace?)

Need help!

Here are the versions:

- GAE: 1.8.7
- Maven: 3.1.1
- Rythm: 1.0-b11-SNAPSHOT
- OS: OS X 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `engine.file_write` configuration to allow Rythm be working with GAE. Check more about the configuration on http://rythmengine.org/doc/configuration.md#engine_file_write_enabled